# Vimscript regex empty line

Tags: regex, vim

So I'm learning Vimscript and Regex. I'm trying to detect if the current line is empty or not. By empty I mean either `""` or `"         "` (any number of spaces/tabs):

```
function! IsCurrentLineEmpty()
    return IsLineEmpty(getline('.'))
endfu

function! IsLineEmpty(line) // returns 1 if the line is empty, 0 otherwise
    if match(a:line, "^\s*$") != -1 // also tried \s+ instead of \s*
        return 1
    endif
endfu
```

If I put the cursor on an empty line or with spaces/tabs, `IsCurrentLineEmpty` always returns 0

I've tried other regex like `^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$` (also `\s\t` and `\s` instead of `' \t'`) but none really worked.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: try `'^\s*$'` or `"^\\s*$"` instead of `"^\s*$"`

Comment: Thank you! Forgot that I had to escape the backslash. Convert to answer if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by @vexe, you just need to escape the backslash. But you can also simplify your function:

```
function! IsLineEmpty(line)
    return match(a:line, "^\\s*$") != -1
endfu
```

Another solution would be to use single quotes instead of double:

```
return match(a:line, '^\s*$') != -1
```

Another solution would be to use Vim's regexp matches operator:

```
return line =~ '^\s*$'
```

Alternatively, you could test if the line contains any non-whitespace characters:

```
return line !~ '[^\s]'
```